# ODBC Driver tracing not capturing any logparser events

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, odbc, logparser

I have enabled Driver Tracing using [these directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattn/enabling-advanced-driver-tracing-for-the-sql-native-client-odbc-drivers). I am running SQL Server 2014, [which uses the 2012 native driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014).

I run the start batch file then the following LogParser command:

> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe" "SELECT SUBSTR(Field1, 0, 2) AS CountryCode, SUBSTR(TO_STRING(Field2), 0, 5) AS Zip INTO ZipCodes  FROM 'c:\Users\jdearing\Downloads\us.txt'" -i:TSV -headerrow:OFF -o:SQL -server . -database LogParserTest -cleartable -transactionRowCount:0  -ignoreMinWarns:OFF

This inserts zero rows. instead producing this error for every row:

```
An error occurred while uploading data to SQL table
  SQL State:     22001
  Native Error:  0
  Error Message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right
  truncation
```

Upon stopping the trace the etl is 1024k, but has no rows according to this logparser query:

> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe" "SELECT * FROM 'SnacTrace_000001.etl'" -i:ETW

I noticed a disparity in the GUIDS in the providers.txt batch file and the output of `logman query providers | findstr SQL`

```
echo {BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI > providers.txt 
echo {A9377239-477A-DD22-6E21-75912A95FD08} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI10 >> providers.txt 
echo {2DA81B52-908E-7DB6-EF81-76856BB47C4F} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI11 >> providers.txt
```

Versus

```
SQLNCLI.1                                {BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5}
SQLSERVER.09                             {AB6D5EEB-0132-74AB-C5F5-B23E1644DADA}
SQLSERVER.10                             {48D59D84-105B-00FA-6B49-03462F696737}
SQLSERVER.11                             {B2A28C42-A7C2-1563-97CC-3BE49FDA19F9}
```

So I updated the batch file to:

```
echo {BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI > providers.txt 
echo {48D59D84-105B-00FA-6B49-03462F696737} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI10 >> providers.txt 
echo {B2A28C42-A7C2-1563-97CC-3BE49FDA19F9} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI11 >> providers.txt
```

Still no luck. What else can I try? Is logparser not using the native client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten data to show up in the ETL. The two things I did were as follows:

- I had to modify the batch file to also set the 32 bit BitInterface Loader: `HKLM\software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\BidInterface\Loader`
- I modified the providers.txt as follows:
  {BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI 
  {A9377239-477A-DD22-6E21-75912A95FD08} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI10.1
  {2DA81B52-908E-7DB6-EF81-76856BB47C4F} 0xFFFFFFFF 128 SQLNCLI11.1

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the `-driver` option explicitly, providing the name of the native client.

Comment: Advice from the author himself.  I'm traveling,  but will try that when I'm in front of the computer again.

Comment: That changes `Error Message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right
  truncation` to `[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]`, but nothing shows up in the traces.

Comment: Well, the error message clearly shows that now LogParser is using the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 driver. As for why the driver's tracing does not show anything, I can't help.